# Backend Server Hosting

Tags: server, backend, hosting, testflight

I have been working on creating a React-Native iOS application with a node.js backend and MongoDB database. I have deployed the frontend to TestFlight for beta testing, however, I was facing some issues with how to host the backend.

Currently, I am running it off of my localhost:3000, but as I look to deploy this app to the App Store, I need a permanent alternative so that the backend isn’t always running off of my computer.

I also don't want it to cost me any money for the time being since it is still in the testing state.

I looked into using Heroku but it doesn’t seem to have a free tier that I can use based on what I saw.

I really need to find an alternative server to host my backend so that it can run continuously not interrupting user use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally use https://railway.app/ which has a really generous free tier.

You can also use Heroku if you are part of the https://education.github.com/pack.

I've heard that https://fly.io/ is also good but I haven't really tried it myself!

Comment: Railway works really well!